# How Do I Set a Long Integer Property in Gremlin JavaScript?

Tags: gremlin, gremlinjs

** PROBLEM **

I need to set a long integer value in a vertex from my JavaScript/TypeScript code.

** WHY IS THIS AN ISSUE? **

JavaScript stores `number` as a `double` in Java or C# world as we can see in the following example:

```
public static async experiment(): Promise<any> {
    const g = GremlinDb.g;
    await g.addV("test")
        .property("number", 3).iterate();
    return {};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `toLong()` in `exports.toLong` in `gremlin-javascript/src/main/javascript/gremlin-javascript/lib/utils.js`

```
public static async experiment(): Promise<any> {
    const g = GremlinDb.g;
    await g.addV("test")
        .property("number", toLong(3)).iterate();
    return {};
}
```